# How to safely reuse glass bottles to store oils

Tags: food-safety, oil, glass

I like to reuse glass bottles and jars in my kitchen in order to create less waste. Recently, I bought a large quantity of olive oil which I would like to use by pouring some of it in an empty 500ml vodka bottle:

[image: 750ml Absolut Vodka bottle]

I have a few concerns, however, since the oil I bought came in a dark glass container which I can only assume is there to protect it from light. I also wonder if it would be fine to simply top off the oil in the bottle once it gets low or if I should clean the bottle every time to ensure it remains safe. Basically, **how can I do this safely?**

Comment: Yes, you can refill when the oil gets low without emptying and washing. I've never had it happen in a case like this but, if it ever smells rancid, obviously you'd want to wash it before adding more oil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

Just wash the bottle with dish soap and hot water.

Unless you do not use the oil in the new bottle frequently, degradation from light should not be an issue; you could store that bottle in a cupboard when not in use (or get a dark glass booze bottle)

Personally, I would try to use a small bottle than a 750ml bottle.

Comment: I'm actually using a 500ml bottle so it should be fine, didn't bother looking for the exact picture.